# How to apply strikethrough() to a tapped foreach Text item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, strikethrough, swiftui-foreach

I'm trying to apply a strikethrough to any tapped Text items in a ForEach loop:

```
struct BrandListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var list: ListObject
                                
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(list.items) { items in
                        Text(item.name)
                            .strikethrough(//?)
                            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                // on tap, apply strikethrough only to this item.
                            })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Is there an easy way to apply a condition using @State var, to track when to apply strikethrough() or not? I'm thinking the only way is to put a property into the listObject that tracks whether it is striked or not, and then use that to apply true/false to the strikethrough() modifier. But that seems like spaghetti code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need it persistent, then definitely you should put it into model. Otherwise, `@State` is only for run-time, you can do it in subview, like

```
ForEach(list.items) { item in
    RowView(item: item)
}
```

and RowView:

```
struct RowView: View {
  let item: Your_Item_Type

  @State private var stroken = false

  var body: some View {
    Text(item.name)
        .strikethrough(stroken)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            self.stroken.toggle()
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply a strikethrough to a TextField view instead of a Text view?

Comment: I think strikethrough only available in iOS 16.0 and above